# Android TFLite and ML Kit: How to resize and normalize bitmap faster?

Tags: android, performance, tensorflow2.0, android-bitmap, tensorflow-lite

I am making an app to detect emotions from video with the help of TFLite. It works smoothly but when I try to add face detection to improve accuracy, I have some problems :

1.FPS downs to a very slow rate ( my testing phone is Samsung Note 9) because ML Kit requires an image bitmap dimension as a minimum of 480x360 pixels and my tflite model needs to get 160x160 pixels image, so I tried to resize the bitmap and it takes so much time!

2.After some time app crashes.

Here is the code to detect face with ML Kit:

```
// High-performance landmark detection and face classification
        val highAccuracyOpts = FaceDetectorOptions.Builder()
            .setPerformanceMode(FaceDetectorOptions.PERFORMANCE_MODE_FAST)
            .setLandmarkMode(FaceDetectorOptions.LANDMARK_MODE_NONE)
            .setClassificationMode(FaceDetectorOptions.CLASSIFICATION_MODE_NONE)
            .setContourMode(FaceDetectorOptions.CONTOUR_MODE_NONE)
            .build()
         
        val bitmap = toBitmap(imageProxy)
        val mediaImage = imageProxy.image
        val image = mediaImage?.let { InputImage.fromMediaImage(it, imageProxy.imageInfo.rotationDegrees) }
       

        val detector = FaceDetection.getClient(highAccuracyOpts)

        detector.process(image!!)
```

and on success:

```
detector.process(image!!)
            .addOnSuccessListener { faces ->

                for (face in faces) {

                    val faceBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                        bitmap!!,
                        face.boundingBox.exactCenterX().toInt()/2,
                        face.boundingBox.exactCenterY().toInt()/2,
                        face.boundingBox.width(),
                        face.boundingBox.height()
                    )

                    val scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(faceBitmap,160,160,true)

                    val my_image = (ctx as Activity).findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.my_face)
                    my_image.setImageBitmap(scaled)

                    // TODO 2: Convert Image to Bitmap then to TensorImage
                    val tfImage = TensorImage.fromBitmap(scaled)

                    // TODO 3: Process the image using the trained model, sort and pick out the top results
                    val outputs = emotionModel.process(tfImage)
                        .probabilityAsCategoryList.apply {
                            sortByDescending { it.score } // Sort with highest confidence first
                        }.take(MAX_RESULT_DISPLAY) // take the top results

                    // TODO 4: Converting the top probability items into a list of recognitions
                    for (output in outputs) {

                        val label = when (output.label) {
                            "happy" -> ctx.getString(R.string.happy)
                            "angry" -> ctx.getString(R.string.angry)
                            "disgust" -> ctx.getString(R.string.disgust)
                            "fear" -> ctx.getString(R.string.fear)
                            "surprise" -> ctx.getString(R.string.surprised)
                            "sad" -> ctx.getString(R.string.sad)
                            "neutral" -> ctx.getString(R.string.neutral)
                            else -> "Idk"
                        }
                        items.add(Recognition(label, output.score))
                    }

                    // Return the result
                    listener(items.toList())
                    imageProxy.close()
                }
                if (faces.size<=0){
                    imageProxy.close()
                }

            }
```

and this is the error I get after some time:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: y + height must be <= bitmap.height()
```

I also tried this:

```
 val faceBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                        bitmap!!,
                        face.boundingBox.left,
                        face.boundingBox.top,
                        face.boundingBox.width(),
                        face.boundingBox.height()
                    )
```

At last, I realize that I didn't normalize my input but I believe in tflite-support metadata section I add this functionality with this code:

```
  input_normalization = _metadata_fb.ProcessUnitT()
input_normalization.optionsType = (
    _metadata_fb.ProcessUnitOptions.NormalizationOptions)
input_normalization.options = _metadata_fb.NormalizationOptionsT()
input_normalization.options.mean = [127.5]
input_normalization.options.std = [127.5]
input_meta.processUnits = [input_normalization]
input_stats = _metadata_fb.StatsT()
input_stats.max = [255]
input_stats.min = [0]
input_meta.stats = input_stats
```

Comment: I have worked with facedetector class and is ... slow to detect faces. So why do you think rescale and normalization is what is causing the problem. In your position I would put some logs to see how much time does it take for each action to finish (face detection, resizing, normalization, inference)

Comment: You are right! I will try this definitely! Do you have any idea about why in the cropping face step I get the "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: y + height must be <= bitmap.height()" error? It could be x+ width too btw.

Comment: Sorry I have to debug and see what line causes that problem. If you have a github account upload and send me the link.

Comment: https://github.com/NusretOzates/Emotion_Detection_Android.git  you need to use "start" module :)

Comment: OK I will try my best.

Comment: 4.1.0-alpha10 or above and Android Studio 4.1 Canary 10 or above is required... :) It will take some time...

Comment: Ups I forget to say that I am so sorry! :D

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217269/discussion-between-farmaker-and-nusret-ozates).

Comment: I am so sorry I can't come right now :( Can we do it tomorrow?

Comment: yes no problem..